# Can any noun type be used as a direct object?

Tags: nouns, direct-objects

Can a noun of any type be used as a direct object?

Comment: Offhand I couldn't easily see how to construct a sentence with ***eternity*** as the "direct object", but Google Bard assures me it is in *I cannot bear eternity in this place.* I can't think of any *more* "awkward" types of noun that can't serve as a direct object. Did you have any *specific* nouns or types of noun in mind?

Comment: Are you thinking of semantic types (feelings / vehicles / habitats ...) or some other classification? As FF says, I'd only think that semantic constraints could apply: some abstract nouns, perhaps. Though sentences like 'This gives rise to an absence of fixed rules and laws' show you'll have to try hard to find an example....  _Although_ including pronouns in the noun word class, 'he', 'she' etc cannot occupy the DO slot.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Obviously subject pronouns ("he/she/they") cannot be a direct object, but object pronouns ("me/him/us/them") can be.

Comment: @Andrew Leach There are signs that subject pronouns are becoming more widespread in situations where they are forced to do double duty ('You should avoid he who will not work for a living') ... and acceptability almost always follows usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yuk.

Comment: This question is quite clear to me. What details are required? (It could possibly belong on ELL; but simply closing without saying how OP is supposed to improve it is... unhelpful.)

Comment: I said about grammar types.

Comment: @AndrewLeach The asker could help by telling us what he means by a "type" of noun, what the possible "types" are to choose from, and whether these are syntactic types or semantic types. I also wonder why he's asking about nouns rather than about noun phrases (NPs) given that most grammars specify NPs  not nouns for a verb's core arguments like its subject and objects. Most objects in English are more complex than a bare noun alone; [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(grammar)#Syntactic_category) for examples of objects of varying syntactic categories.

Comment: [Certain nouns](https://www.babbel.com/en/magazine/english-fossil-words) such as "loggerheads", "dint", "dudgeon", "wedlock" allegedly only occur in prepositional phrases: "at loggerheads", "by dint of", "in high dudgeon", "in/out of wedlock", etc. So possibly they can't be used as direct objects. These are known as fossil words, so some fossil words can't be used as direct objects, although others  like "vim" or "kith" could ("I admire his vim and vigor", "I respect kith and kin"). It still comes down to the question what is a noun type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [scribbr](https://www.scribbr.co.uk/category/nouns/)*, nouns can be classified into a number of different types. Most can be used as a direct object. This answer doesn't consider pronouns, because the question doesn't ask about pronouns.

- common nouns

  > I painted the **fence.**
- proper nouns

  > I like **London.**
- countable nouns

  > I recited **facts.**
- uncountable (mass) nouns

  > I recited **poetry.**
- concrete nouns

  > I folded the **leaflet.**
- abstract nouns

  > I appreciate **beauty.**
- collective nouns

  > I sacked the **team.**
- possessive nouns

  > I parked my car. I crashed my **sister’s.**

  *(This might be debatable; is* sister's *here a pronoun, or functioning as a pronoun, and does that mean that a possessive noun on its own can't be a direct object?)*
- gerunds

  > I enjoy **whistling.**
- generic nouns

  > I hate **people.**
- attributive nouns

  These can't be used as a direct object because the noun phrase is the object — the main noun is necessary:

  > I like **carrot** cake.
- appositive nouns

  Again, these can't be used as a direct object because the noun phrase is the object — the main noun is necessary:

  > I like my colleague **Adam.**

* Scribbr is simply used as a convenient list. No endorsement is intended.